# Pass value in form using the amforms plugin

Tags: form, plugin-amforms

I've created a (apply for a job) form using [amforms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms).
I'm using this form for multiple jobs. Whenever someone replies with this form, I want to pass the job name in the form.

I've tries many thing but can't find a solution.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the title of the entry is the name of the job. So if that's the case, just add a hidden input in the form and add the entry's title to the value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[jobTitle]" value="{{ entry.title }}">
```

Then make sure to create a 'jobTitle' text field in the CMS and attach it to that form.

Comment: does not work for me !

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what's not working so I can maybe help you out?  Did you create the "jobTitle" field in the plugin?  Is the entry's title printing to the page?  Are you sure it's a problem related to this issue?  You gotta provide some details when posting.